# Why is the -e option not in the bash command manual?

Tags: bash, man

I'm a little confused about the missing -e option from the bash manual. `man bash`

But it is working with a script shebang like : `#!/bin/bash -e` and of course it is defined in `help set`.

Why isn't it listed in the options in the bash manual ?

Comment: `set` is part of bash; _all_ of its options are present in the bash manual.

Comment: Obligatory _see also_: [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Nowadays, the [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) are also available online (requires an Internet connection and a web browser of some sort), though if using a search engine to find them, it should be restricted to the site where they are known to exist, e.g. *linux.die.net*. [Sample, for 'bash'](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is implicitly mentioned at the start of the manual:

> OPTIONS
> All of the single-character shell options documented in the description
> of the `set` builtin command, including `-o`, can be used as options when
> the shell is invoked.  [...]

You are then expected to look up the `set` builtin command further down in the manual, use `help set` in an interactive shell session (as you mention in the question), or access the longer reference manual in some appropriate way (e.g. by using the `info bash set` command, on systems where this works).

Comment: Or `info bash set` to get to the `set` documentation directly. `info -n invoking bash` for the section that contains your quote (section 6.1) with a hyperlink to the `set` section.

Comment: Unlike the man page, the ["Invoking Bash" section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash) in the reference manual also mentions the short options in the invocation synopsis: `bash [long-opt] [-abefhkmnptuvxdBCDHP] [-o option] ...`

Answer (score 9):

It is in the bash(1) man page under `set`. On some systems, including Debian-based ones, you'll also find a bash-builtins(7) or even builtins(7) man page that covers only the builtin commands of that shell where the information may be easier to find.

> ...
>
> ```
>   -e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist  of  a
>           single  simple  command),  a list, or a compound command
>           (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero status.
>           The  shell  does  not  exit if the command that fails is
>           part of the command list immediately following  a  while
>           or  until  keyword, part of the test following the if or
>           elif reserved words, part of any command executed  in  a
>           &&  or || list except the command following the final &&
>           or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the
>           command's  return  value is being inverted with !.  If a
>           compound command other than a subshell  returns  a  non-
>           zero  status because a command failed while -e was being
>           ignored, the shell does not exit.  A  trap  on  ERR,  if
>           set,  is  executed  before the shell exits.  This option
>           applies to the shell environment and each subshell envi‐
>           ronment  separately  (see  COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT
>           above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
>           all the commands in the subshell.
>
>           If  a  compound  command or shell function executes in a
>           context where -e is being ignored, none of the  commands
>           executed  within  the  compound command or function body
>           will be affected by the -e setting, even if  -e  is  set
>           and  a  command returns a failure status.  If a compound
>           command or shell function sets -e while executing  in  a
>           context  where -e is ignored, that setting will not have
>           any effect until the compound  command  or  the  command
>           containing the function call completes.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   errexit Same as -e.
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Yes, but the description for the `set` builtin _doesn't say_ that its options can be given to the shell as options when starting it. Many other builtins also take options but those can't be given as options to the shell itself (nor would they make sense). The fact that `set` options are different needs to be picked up from somewhere else. (e.g. under the "OPTIONS" section).